# Octopress update gh-pages branch

Tags: github, branch, jekyll, octopress

I have setup Octopress on my github account. I have 3 branchs; source, master, gh-pages. When i add a new blog post, generates locally but does not updates on my github account's gh-pages branch. I have tried to commit, push into gh-pages branch, but i get "nothing to commit, working directory clean" message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I took a look at your [Rakefile](https://github.com/jspduke/www.alperunal.com/blob/source/Rakefile) : `deploy_branch = "master"` must be `deploy_branch = "gh-pages"`.

#### Let's fix this

```
# go to site root
cd /your/folder

# be sure to be on the source branch
git checkout source

# make a backup (Shit happens)
cp -rp . ../save.alperunal

# remove the gh-pages branch on github
git push origin --delete gh-pages

# setup the deploy folder on gh-pages
rake setup_github_pages[git@github.com:jspduke/www.alperunal.com.git]

# deploy your code
rake gen_deploy
```

Good, you're now pushing in `gh-pages`. As everything is good now your can :

- delete the backup `rm -rf ../save.alperunal`
- go to github, make your `source` as default branch and remove `master`

Comment: My remote origin looks correct. Checked .git/config. Still got same problem.

Comment: Do you have a github repository ?